# weired StatementInvalid error when building many-to-many relationship form in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Hello I'm making a form for establishing many-to-many relationship between two models

using this [solution](http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/)

I Have Three Model

Artist, Article, ArtistRelationship.

This is Artist Model.

```
 class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
   default_scope order('created_at DESC')

   attr_accessible :body_en, :body_kr, :title_en, :title_kr

   has_many :articles, :through => :artist_relationships
   has_many :artist_relationships
 end
```

And this is Article Model.

```
 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope order('created_at DESC')

    attr_accessible :title, :body, :date

    has_many :artists, :through => :artist_relationships
    has_many :artist_relationships

 end
```

And this is ArtistRelationship Model

```
 class ArtistRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
   default_scope order('created_at DESC')

   attr_accessible :article_id, :artist_id

   belongs_to :artist
   belongs_to :article

 end
```

Now I have a form for an article to set the artists.

```
 <%= form_for [:admin, article] do |f| %>
   .....
     <% Artist.all.each do |artist| %>
        <div>
           <%= label_tag :artist_ids, artist.title_kr %>
           <%= check_box_tag :artist_ids, artist.id, article.artists.include?(artist), :name => 'article[artist_ids][]' %>
        </div>
     <% end %>
```

**The error come from here**

```
 article.artists.include?(artist)
```

It raises these error

> Mysql2::Error: Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous: SELECT  1 AS one FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `artist_relationships` ON `artists`.`id` = `artist_relationships`.`artist_id` WHERE `artist_relationships`.`article_id` = 1 AND `artists`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1

I can't get what it means..

And **weired** thing occurs when I use pry to debug right above the code

```
 <%= check_box_tag :artist_ids, artist.id, article.artists.include?(artist), :name => 'article[artist_ids][]' %>
```

in pry console when I directly call `article.artists.include?(artist)`

It raise same error as I expected. but

When I call  `article.artists` it returns an array of artist belongs to that article

then I call `article.artists.include?(artist)` again. I works fine.

What's the problem of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in all your default scope, include the tableized version of the class

```
# article.rb
default_scope order('articles.created_at DESC')
```